# How to reference previously defined styles

Tags: sass

I am new to sass, and I have h1, h2, h3 defined in a .sass file, and I want to do something like the following:

```
h1 {
   font-size: 25px;
}

.section {
   h1 { font-size: h1.font-size - 5px; }
}
```

I know the syntax is incorrect, but I think you get the gist.  Would really appreciate it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll have to store the value in a variable:

```css
$h1-font-size: 25px;

h1 {
   font-size: $h1-font-size;

   .section & {
       font-size: $h1-font-size - 5;
   }
}
```

This'll produce the following CSS:

```css
h1 { font-size: 25px; }
.section h1 { font-size: 20px; }
```

Comment: It's an interesting thought, though. It would probably lead to a lot of abuse, but maybe the capacity to read previous rules could be used to make easy-to-use Sass mixins that can be used across projects, for instance to allow UI modules to blend in with the surrounding colour scheme *without* having to give any parameters.